# IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Does anybody know what this means?

```
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:234)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.bindString(SQLiteQuery.java:182)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:48)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:330)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:280)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at net.lp.collectionista.providers.ProductContentProvider.query(ProductContentProvider.java:350)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:163)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:245)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at net.lp.collectionista.providers.FacadeContentProvider.query(FacadeContentProvider.java:563)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:163)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:245)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at net.lp.collectionista.util.ScanAddTask.existsProduct(ScanAddTask.java:164)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at net.lp.collectionista.util.ScanAddTask.<init>(ScanAddTask.java:71)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at net.lp.collectionista.util.ItemScanAddTask.<init>(ItemScanAddTask.java:34)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at net.lp.collectionista.ui.activities.collections.cd.CDCollectionViewWindow$MusicCDItemScanAddTask.<init>(CDCollectionViewWindow.java:147)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at net.lp.collectionista.ui.activities.collections.cd.CDCollectionViewWindow.restoreLocalState(CDCollectionViewWindow.java:1044)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at net.lp.collectionista.ui.activities.collections.cd.CDCollectionViewWindow.onRestoreInstanceState(CDCollectionViewWindow.java:966)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:815)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
12-31 20:55:45.861: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
```

Comment: It means you have an illegal argument somewhere. Presumably you're passing null somewhere that it can't be null.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

`The bind value` apparently refers to the `selectionArgs` for the selection, that you insert into `query()`. If such a `selectionArgs` value is `null`, you get this.

Comment: Umm, I appreciate this is an old post, but what if you want to search for NULL like I am trying to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175233/how-to-search-for-null-in-android-database-query-or-statement-in-selection

Comment: My issue was that the selection wasn't fully correct. I missed the `?` so I had `columnName` instead of `columnName +"=?"`.

Comment: Something that wasn't immediately apparent to me: selectionArgs is an array, and if *one the values is null*, you'll get this error.

Answer (score 3):

`@Gray` and `@pjv` response was the point for realize what problem caused this error. You have to be careful with selection and selectionArgs matching, if you pass `selection = null` and `selectionArgs = something`, you will get this error too! :) Thnks!

Answer (score 1):

This does not exactly relate to the question, but I was facing a similiar issue for me the `argument containted a dash (-) at the beginning`.  This was causing the issue.

So I escaped the argument like this

```
return mDatabase.query(table_name,
                       null,
                       column_name + "=?",
                       new String[]{"\\" + argument},
                       null,
                       null,
                       null);
```

This solved it for me.

You can also see this : [How to escape special characters like ' in sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/how-to-escape-special-characters-like-in-sqlite-in-android)