# How to escape special characters like ' in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, special-characters

I have a function which is executing a query on a table in SQLite database.  I declare a constant: `public static final String CANADA_HISTORY = "Canada's History";`. This is stored in a `String` variable let's say `difficulty`,

I have one query:

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select * from Questions_answers where CHAPTERS = '"+difficulty+"'" , null);
```

It is throwing an exception near the apostrophe.

Logcat output:

```
I/Database( 1170): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "s": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime( 1170): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1170): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1170): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error: , while compiling: select * from Questions_answers where CHAPTERS  = 'Canada's History'
```

I have also tried:

```
1.  difficulty=difficulty.replaceAll("'","''");
2.  difficulty=difficulty.replaceAll("'","\'");
3.  difficulty = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(difficulty);
```

To add to that, it's working me for the single words like `Canada History`, I mean without the special character word.

Please give me advice for the solve   problem Thanks.

Comment: try using `selectionArgs`, for e.g. : `rawQuery("select * from table where chapters = ?", new String[] { difficulty } );`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First replace char with this

```
difficulty=difficulty.replaceAll("'","\\'");
```

then pass it in your query

```
"select * from Questions_answers where CHAPTERS='"+difficulty+"'";
```

**Edit :**

```
 q = "select * from Questions_answers where CHAPTERS = ?";
    database.rawQuery(q, new String[] { difficulty});
```

Comment: What about dash, hyphen "-" character?

Comment: The edit looks OK, but the first part of the answer is obviously wrong. `"'"` is the same string as `"\'"` (the latter is just alternative notation for the same character sequence), so the `replace()` statement is effectively an identity function. Funny it's the accepted answer.

Comment: Franz is right, this will not work, did not work for me.

Answer (score 89):

***The SQL standard specifies that single-quotes in strings are escaped by putting two single quotes in a row. SQL works like the Pascal programming language in the regard. SQLite follows this standard. Example:***

```
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES('5 O''clock');
```

Ref : [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14)

Comment: this is horrible. Use selectionArgs. don't try to sanitize the sql inputs yourself.

Comment: @njzk2 Hey Thanks for pointing. But it would be better if you add details about "why is it horrible?". This would help other users :). By the way I did not get your points here, because this answer was for escaping special characters.

Comment: This question is targeted at SQLite in Android. The OP asks how to input characters such as `'` in a query. The proper answer is to use `selectArgs`, which leaves the escaping/sanitizing/... work to the SQLite module itself, which it does well, and comprehensively. What you suggests only works for `'`.

Comment: Comments of this sort are silly.  There's absolutely no reason someone can't successfully implement their own string sanitizer.  It's one of the simplest ways to build your own methods for dynamically building queries, which isn't the easiest thing to do with argument processors.

Comment: I need to export a result of combining tables into a textfile which I can include in a SQlite browser. I dump a few hundred lines in it and voila. If it is sanitized by me, nog selectionArgs :)

Answer (score 55):

The best way is to use a native Android method designed for exactly this purpose:

```
DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(String)
```

Here is the documentation for it online:

- [sqlEscapeString() on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String))

The main advantage of using this method, in my opinion, is the self-documentation because of the clear method name.

Comment: I ran into trouble with queries, after using this function, since it definitely surrounds your string with single quotes, which are then part of your string and you have to adapt your queries accordingly or use another method to escape strings. More details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334723/how-to-use-string-field-in-where-clause-in-android-sqlite/33684053#33684053

Comment: @Carsten this question relates to the use of raw query strings. For obvious reasons you would not use it in conjunction with the other helper methods, they do this internally already. Hence the issue you and the other poster were experiencing.

Comment: The source code of that utils method suggests that it only escapes `'` characters and surrounds the input strng with two quotes as well `'`

Answer (score 28):

What worked for me was

```
if (columnvalue.contains("'")) {
    columnvalue = columnvalue.replaceAll("'", "''");
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I also added a null check before it to be safe. I can't believe GOOG's own DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString() method is such junk.

Comment: String.replaceAll creates a Pattern. I'm not sure it's very optimal just to replace `'`

Answer (score 4):

you can try `Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select * from Questions_answers where CHAPTERS = \""+difficulty+"\"" , null);`

Comment: It is Work For Me. Thanks jaredzhang. It is Just Easy to Solve this special character problem.

Answer (score 3):

What `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(s)` essentially does, is replace all single quotes (`'`) with two single quotes (`''`) and append one single quote at the beginning and one at the end of the String.
So if you just want to escape the String this function should work:

```
private static String escape(String s) {
    return s != null ? s.replaceAll("\'", "\'\'") : null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work the same:

```
if (columnValue.contains("'")) 
    columnValue = columnValue.replaceAll("'", "[']");
```

or

```
if (columnValue.contains("'")) 
    columnValue = columnValue.replaceAll("'", "\\\'");
```

but in actuality we use next symbols % and _

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding there are two approcaches,

> String test= "Android's vaersion"
>       test= test.replace("'","''");

This scenario is absolutely fine but i would definitely suggest to use following  approach.

> String test= "Android's vaersion"
>       test= test.replaceAll("'","\'");

We faced the issue because of first approach when we were trying to update and select SQLite Table Value with '.

Answer (score -2):

don't you need to escape the \ as well?  so it would be `replaceAll("'", "\\'")` Or am I wrong about that?