# Android: store in SQLite a string with the character '

Tags: android, sqlite, character, store, quote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape special characters like ' in sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/how-to-escape-special-characters-like-in-sqlite-in-android)

I'm using a form to store some values in an Android's SQLite database. If any of the fields contains the character ' an error occurs so I tried to escape it, but the error is still there.

This is my code:

```
public boolean createCalendar(String id, String name, String descr) {
    try{
        String newDescr = descr.replace("'", "\\'");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Calendar (id, name, description) VALUES " +
                "('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+newDescr+"');");
       ...
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "siksjs": syntax error, db=/data/data/com.pfc.app/databases/SSDB
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "siksjs": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Calendar (id, name, description) VALUES ('43779fcb-3d8c-650b-b529-50810506375e','kdldlls','ddk \' siksjs');
```

How am I supposed to store it?

Thanks!

Comment: use `DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(String)` [as per this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27082084/383414). It was designed precisely for this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
p_query = "select * from mytable where name_field = ?";
mDb.rawQuery(p_query, new String[] { uvalue });
```

Or

```
String newDescr = descr.replaceAll("'", "''");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/how-to-escape-special-characters-like-in-sqlite-in-android