# Syntax error while passing Sql Query to Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, select

I am trying to execute query like

```
Select  * From Table_name where English=' + word + "'"
```

and error i am getting is

```
09-23 07:41:21.995: E/AndroidRuntime(4693): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select  * From Table_Name where English='MA'AM'
```

I have refered the link [android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "...": syntax error (code 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962880/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-near-syntax-error-code-1) but that also gives me error like

```
09-23 08:27:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5581): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "MA": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select  * From Tabel_Name where English=?MA'AM
```

So my question is how can i pass this query with **MA'AM** this kind of words.

PS: Other words which does not have **'** is working fine so there is no issue with any other code, just query only which is creating problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: learn about prepared statements

Comment: @Jens, I am android developer so i dont have much knowledge of SQL, but still if you can provide any URL or example that would be better to understand the scenario...

Comment: Which database you are talking about?

Comment: @laalto, i am getting error if i use the query like in that question... So please do not mark this question as duplicate.. That this is different scenario...

Comment: It's the same: `'` in a SQL string literal is a problem and the best solution is to use `?` variables and bind the values.

Comment: @laalto, Even i have tried with **?** also but still i am getting the same error, i have updated my question also with that error

Comment: @laalto, Can you tell me how can i fire query to get all words which contains ', this would be big help from your side

Comment: Don't include the `MA'AM` in the SQL at all - just the `?`. The value `MA'AM` should go in `selectionArgs`.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to write like this

```
English='MA''AM'
```

Comment: So what if words have only String like **MAM**, i mean word which does not have any **'**, whether this query work with that words too..

Comment: dynamically you have to replace it 'MA''AM'

Comment: Can you tell me how can i fire query to get all words which contains **'**, this would be big help from your side.

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM TableName
 WHERE FieldName LIKE '%''%'

Comment: this will get you all records which contains '

Comment: Thanks man that quesry works...