# insert string using sqlite in android containing single and double quotes in it

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having trouble with inserting a string using sqlite in an android app,
I tried,

```
query  = "INSERT OR REPLACE into table(_id, text) VALUES ("+data.get(i).id+", '"+data.get(i).text+"')";
MyClass.db.execSQL(query);
```

If my string looks like,

```
'I'm an android developer'
```

App crashes here, here is logcat result,

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "m": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE into table (_id, text) VALUES (4, '"I'm an android developer"' )
```

I think it assumes that, my query ends here

```
'"I'
```

please help me to insert any case of string, either it contains  single or double quotes like,

```
"I'm an "android" developer"
```

Comment: You need to remove the special symbol `'` comma.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/how-to-escape-special-characters-like-in-sqlite-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any hardcoding or anything you can directly insert with using `ContentValues` like below..

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
long retvalue = 0;
values.put("_id", id_here);
values.put("text", your_text_here);
retvalue = MyClass.db.insertWithOnConflict(table, null, values, CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Comment: @LS_dev thank you for edit and you  make it as a suitable answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using normal `insert statement` and if you have any value which contains single quote in it, then you might face a weird issue like this. So,try this..

```
String insert_info = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table(_id,text) VALUES (?,?)";
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(insert_info);
stmt.bindString(1, ""+data.get(i).id);
stmt.bindString(2, ""+data.get(i).text);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Better to use built-in [insertWithOnConflict](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options:

1. Use `ContentValues` with `SQLiteDatabase.insert()`
2. Use variable binding, e.g.

   ```
   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO table(_id, text) VALUES(?,?)", new String[] { idValue, textValue });
   ```
3. Escape the `'` in strings. The SQL way to escape it is `''` and you can use [`DatabaseUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) helpers to do the escaping.

To escape the `"` in Java strings, use `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

you must replace \' with \'\' in query string:

```
String getQuery(){
    query  = "INSERT OR REPLACE into table(_id, text) VALUES ("+data.get(i).id+", '"+getSqlValue(data.get(i).text)+"')";
    MyClass.db.execSQL(query);
    return query;
}
String getSqlValue(String input){
    return input.replace("\'","\'\'");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `&quot;` for skipping `"` in a string

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.