# Insert data to database with execsql

Tags: database, insert

I can insert data to my database with this:

```
mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (NAME, CITY) VALUES 
('John','Toronto')");
```

But if I use the parameter as fallow for CITY, my application crashes:

```
String str2="Toronto";
mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (NAME, CITY) VALUES 
('John',str2)");
```

why?

Comment: Please post the error message also (formatted as code).

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? What programming language is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str2='Toronto';
```

Try using single quotations otherwise execSQL will assume your query ends at the double quotes.

This may help explain [insert string using sqlite in android containing single and double quotes in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608543/insert-string-using-sqlite-in-android-containing-single-and-double-quotes-in-it)

Comment: Using single quotation will cause this error: Error:(47, 26) error: unclosed character literal

Comment: Would this work? `mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (NAME, CITY) VALUES 
('John',"+str2+")");`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. my application crashes with this.

Comment: this is the right code: mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (NAME, CITY) VALUES ('John',' "+str2+" ')");