# Unity App42 SDK - storing score id in SQLite DB

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine, app42

I'm implementing a leaderboard service with App42 Unity SDK. The basic workflow is to save user's score first time, get the returned score id as described in [tutorials](http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Managing-Leaderboard/),store it in the device local SQLite DB and then update the user score with that score id periodically.

The issue is that score id returned as a string which may contain SQLite invalid characters. "0QE9+50fILUfGERTTRIxLvmRRH8=" is one of such. How would you deal with the issue?

Comment: Could you store the string value as a binary value?

Comment: You can use your own custom encoding to replace +/= with some string and decode the same after fetching.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/how-to-escape-special-characters-like-in-sqlite-in-android

Comment: Well, storing it as a binary blob was the easiest way. Just a little mess of storing and reading it back with kind of a limited API I've got to work with SQLite in Unity, but not more than a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your score ID in PlayerPrefs as string instead of SQLite

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("ScoreID", score.scoreID);
```