# How to find list of escape character for sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want list of `escape character` for `sqlite` in `android` to add backslash before those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape special characters like ' in sqlite in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/how-to-escape-special-characters-like-in-sqlite-in-android)

Comment: @ChrisS : sorry but I want list of escape character not how to

Comment: I want list also for character like `-` `,` `'` Possible that prepare statement is the only way to manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL does not use backslashes for escaping.

When string literals are written directly in the SQL command, they are delimited with single quotes; any single quote inside the string must be doubled.:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Text = 'with '' quote'",
                     null);
```

Table/column names can be delimited with double quotes; any double quote in the table/column name must be doubled.

If you use parameters (which is stronly recommended), you do not need to escape anything:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Text = ?",
                     new String[]{ "with ' quote" });
```