# Replace all 'char' in string to 'charchar'

Tags: swift, string, algorithm, sqlite

Bumping into an issue when inserting data to SQLite. In SQLite we have to write two single quote(') when we want to add a value containing (').
[How to escape special characters like ' in sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615113/how-to-escape-special-characters-like-in-sqlite-in-android/27082084)

---

### Question

How to replace all (') in string to ('')?

> My bro's watch is 8 o'clock ==> My bro''s watch is 8 o''clock

It's better if the answer is written in Swift.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use replace all method just before adding in to sqlite.