# Failed Login Validation Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, authentication

I have a big problem when trying to login on my android screen. I have two fields that requires user to enter email and password, it should then go and check sqlite db if correct they will be navigated to mainscreen(login success) if incorrect they will be notified via toast message. My problem is when i hit login button my app displays "Unfortunately stopped working" I cant see any errors in my code! Please someone help!!My code is posted below
***LoginActivity**

```
package com.example.finalproject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    Button mLogin;
    Button mNewUser;
    Button mShowAll;
    EditText mUsername;
    EditText mPassword;
    SQLiteAdapter mydb = null;
    private String uname;
    private String pass;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mNewUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNewUser);
        mNewUser.setOnClickListener(this);

        mLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

        mShowAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonShowAll);
        mShowAll.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteAdapter(LoginActivity.this).openToWrite();
        if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonLogin) {
            mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
            mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);

            String uname = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();

            if(uname.equals("") || uname == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Empty", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(pass.equals("") || pass == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email= ? AND password=?", new String[] {uname, pass});
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(main);
        } 
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
}
```

**SQLIteAdapter**

```
package com.example.finalproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SQLiteAdapter {

 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_DEVELOPMENT_PROJECT_DATABASE";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_USERS_TABLE";
 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
 public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";


 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
  "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
  + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
  + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
  + KEY_EMAIL + " text not null, "
  + KEY_PASSWORD + " text not null);";

 private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

 private Context context;

 public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
  context = c;
 }

 public SQLiteAdapter(SQLiteAdapter sqLiteAdapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public SQLiteDatabase openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  return sqLiteDatabase; 
 }

 public SQLiteDatabase openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,
                MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase;
    }
 /*public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }*/

 public void close(){
  sqLiteHelper.close();
 }

 public long insert(String name, String email, String password){

  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  contentValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
  contentValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
  return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
 }

 public int deleteAll(){
  return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
 }

 public Cursor queueAll(){
  String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PASSWORD};
  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
    null, null, null, null, null);

  return cursor;
 }

 public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
    CursorFactory factory, int version) {
   super(context, name, factory, version);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
 }




}
```

**RegisteActivty**

```
package com.example.finalproject;






import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

 EditText inputName, inputEmail, inputPassword;
 Button buttonRegister, buttonDeleteAll;
 TextView login;
 private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
 ListView listContent;

 SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
 Cursor cursor;


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);


       inputName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
       inputEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
       inputPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
       buttonRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
       //buttonDeleteAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showAll);

       listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

       mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
       mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

       cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
      // String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_NAME, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_EMAIL,SQLiteAdapter.KEY_PASSWORD};
       /*int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2,R.id.text3};
       cursorAdapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
       listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);*/

       buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);
       //buttonShowAll.setOnClickListener(buttonShowAllOnClickListener);
       //addListenerOnRegButton();

       TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);

       // Listening to login 
       loginScreen.setOnClickListener(TextLoginOnClickListener);
}

TextView.OnClickListener TextLoginOnClickListener
= new TextView.OnClickListener(){



@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
};

   Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener
   = new Button.OnClickListener(){



  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {



   String data1 = inputName.getText().toString();
   String data2 = inputEmail.getText().toString();
   String data3 = inputPassword.getText().toString();

   boolean invalid = false;

    if(data1.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(data2.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ID Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(data3.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(invalid == false){
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, data2, data3);
        updateList();
           Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You are now registered",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i_register = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i_register);

        inputName.setText("");
        inputEmail.setText("");
        inputPassword.setText("");
        finish();
    }   




  }

   };




  /*Button.OnClickListener buttonShowAllOnClickListener1
   = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
      Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
  }

   };

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDestroy();
  mySQLiteAdapter.close();
 }*/



 private void updateList(){
  //cursor.requery();
   }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at com.example.finalproject.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:62)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-04 02:55:56.085: E/AndroidRuntime(17402):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 02:55:56.555: D/dalvikvm(17402): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 11% free 3060K/3436K, paused 126ms+33ms, total 459ms
02-04 03:00:56.444: I/Process(17402): Sending signal. PID: 17402 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I think you have not open the sqlite database like db.open() may be exception is due to that

Comment: i have open db by calling SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteAdapter(LoginActivity.this).openToWrite()

Comment: sorry my bad I didn't see that. What code exactly is on you LoginActivity.java:62 line please let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes in this line:

`db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email= ? AND password=?", new String[] {uname, pass})`

What's happening is that **even if** your `if` statement outputs a Toast to say that the edittexts are empty, this section gets executed, so `uname` and `pass` are null, which is giving you the `IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null` error, as you're passing the SQL function null values.

Simple fix: only execute the bottom section of code if the values aren't null or empty:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteAdapter(LoginActivity.this).openToWrite();
    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonLogin) {
        mUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Username);
        mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);

        String uname = mUsername.getText().toString();
        String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();

        if(uname.equals("") || uname == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username Empty", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(pass.equals("") || pass == null){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email= ? AND password=?", new String[] {uname, pass});
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                 startActivity(main);
            }  else {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I am very new to android and not sure how to do this

Comment: It's not really an Android issue, more a general code logic and flow problem. I've updated my answer with the manipulation of your code - it was just putting an `else` statement in, and moving the `(if view ==...` end brace to cover the whole method

Comment: You are the best!!I have spent so much time on this, been up half the nite, thank u so much :)

Comment: No worries. For future reference, what I did was have a look at your logcat, and look for the first instance of this: `at com.example.finalproject`. Then you see where it's happening: `LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:62)`, which tells you exactly the line at which the error occurs. I then looked through your `onClick` method, found the database call with parameters, and line 1 of your logcat trace told me that the parameter at index 2 was null

Answer (score 1):

This thread might help you ...[IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572090/android-sql-illegalargumentexception-the-bind-value-at-index-1-is-null)

Check if your selArgs are not null ..