# String null after object creating in constructor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sugarorm

I'm passing String to RecyclerView.Adapter in order to use it as Database query parameter, but stranger things, I'm getting this String as null.

I tried to use not static String, but it didn't help

String from Activity is passed to Adapter correctly and isn't null, but in Adapter there is something strange.

Could you please advise what's wrong?

Adapter:

```
  public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.FoodViewHolder> {

     public FoodAdapter(String s) {

    foodDataList = Food.findWithQuery(Food.class, "Select * from Food where type = ?", s);

}



    public class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        private ImageView food_image;
        private TextView name;
        private TextView description;
        private TextView price;

        public FoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            food_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_image);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        }

        public void bind(Food food) {
            name.setText(food.getName());
            description.setText(food.getDescription());
            price.setText("Цена: " + String.valueOf(food.getPrice()));
            Picasso.get().load(String.valueOf(food.getPicture())).into(food_image);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public FoodAdapter.FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new FoodViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FoodAdapter.FoodViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.bind( foodDataList.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodDataList.size();
    }
    }
```

Activity:

```
package com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe.View;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe.Model.BackendlessData;
import com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe.Presenter.FoodAdapter;
import com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe.R;

    public class SandwichActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sandwich);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String FOODTYPE = intent.getStringExtra("TypeSandwich");


        FoodAdapter foodAdapterSandwich = new FoodAdapter(FOODTYPE);


        RecyclerView foodRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sandwich_recycler_view);
        foodRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        foodRecyclerView.setAdapter(foodAdapterSandwich);
    }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
 Process: com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe, PID: 10323
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe/com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe.View.SandwichActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.findWithQuery(SugarRecord.java:181)
        at com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe.Presenter.FoodAdapter.<init>(FoodAdapter.java:34)
        at com.kosenin.boston.bronxcafe.View.SandwichActivity.onCreate(SandwichActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Try not to use static String. And check in the constructor wt value you are receiving

Comment: probably, this: intent.getStringExtra("TypeSandwich"); returns null

Comment: just write the private List<Food> foodDataList =... inside constructor..

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572090/illegalargumentexception-the-bind-value-at-index-1-is-null

Comment: @Stultuske I checked that in debugger, it returns the right value

Comment: @KoustuvGanguly tried that, but getting the same error. In debugger it looks like that: public FoodAdapter(String s) // correct value I've passed from activity {
        this.foodtype = s // Nothing;

    }

Comment: @Amit could you please give a bit more details? Shall I initialize the list in constructor? Is it correct?

Comment: @KapilRajput thank you, I've read that thread before asking, my trouble is exactly the same, but I don't realize why the String is null after initializing the object in constructor

Comment: @Konstantin, you have to initialise the list inside constructor or other functions..You can't initialised the list in declaration statement.

Comment: @Amit thank you for advice, now the error is gone. But the list itself is empty... foodDataList.size() = 0

Comment: Please update the code in this post...

Comment: @Amit code is updated, please take a look at constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make this changes into your code.

1. remove query part from adapter also adapter handle only bind there for your recycler view work faster.logical part also in activity or fragment.

adapater change..

```
 List<Food> foodDataList = new ArrayList<>();// hear you can pass any pojo class object.
Context mContext;

public FoodAdapter(List<Food> foodDataList, Context mContext) {
    this.foodDataList = foodDataList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

and in main activity..

```
   List<Food> foodList=db.readFoodData(); // here your database read opration and give list of food
    FoodAdapter foodAdapterSandwich = new FoodAdapter(foodList,this);


    RecyclerView foodRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sandwich_recycler_view);
    foodRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    foodRecyclerView.setAdapter(foodAdapterSandwich);
    foodAdapterSandwich.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and make sure your database query work and it give list of food data.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have 2 questions, why do I need context in Adapter and is it really bad practice to pass logic to Adapter?

Comment: you can put logical part into adapter but never put into onBindViewHolder method because this method always call when you scroll recyclerview then you put logical part into that then it work slow.